# calling convention when using 64bit unmanaged callback

Tags: c#, pinvoke, 32bit-64bit, unmanaged

I have an unmanaged handler used in C# code, the delegate is defined like

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public delegate int Callback (arguments)
```

It works well in 32bit version and I'm asking me what changes have to be done in 64bit version. The C header of the dll  containing the handler defines all functions as `__stdcall` if WIN32 and  as `__fastcall` if WIN64 (i.e. the dll comes in both 32 and 64bit versions).  But in NET documentation it is said that fastcall is not supported.  I don't understand what all this means, how should I change (or not) the code for 64 bits ?

Comment: Use 32 bit version since 64 bit version is a fastcall and Net doc says fastcall is not supported.

Comment: the dlls and the C headers come with a hardware I bought, I haven't written it.  So I understand your -1 is for the hardware vendor.

Comment: Write unmanaged wrappers that employ `__stdcall` and forward to the `__fastcall` versions (or use C++/CLI to immediately expose these functions as managed ones), and the other way around for callbacks (pass a `__fastcall` delegate to the unmanaged code that calls the `__stdcall` managed callback). You probably don't want to do that by hand if there's a lot of functions, so some code to generate them might be needed.

Comment: All this is necessary only if the 32-bit version *can't run* on 64-bit Windows (which might be the case if it interfaces directly with a driver). If it can, simply compile your managed code as "Prefer 32-bit" and use the 32-bit versions exclusively, that's much simpler.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen for the suggestion. Actually my code can run in 32bit on 64bit Windows (if the 32bit version of the external dll is used). But I also distribute a C# source so I don't know on which architecture and with which driver version it will be used (I might also just prevent users to compile only in x86 mode). That said I find it strange - why the manufacturer would want to make it so complicated?

Comment: It's probable the manufacturer isn't concerned at all with .NET code interfacing with the DLL. In unmanaged code, this is simply not a concern since you #include the headers and away you go. No source needs to be modified since the calling convention is part of the (presupplied) header. If the supplier *was* concerned about managed code, they would have supplied the API themselves. Building hardware and writing drivers is hard enough -- managed code is Someone Else's Problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. Calling convention directives are ignored when targeting 64 bit code because there is a single calling convention for that architecture. Leave the code as it is. It will work correctly for both 32 and 64 bit compilation.